# Why was this question on filter design and its hardware description migrated to Statistical Analysis SE?

Tags: discussion

Why was the question below migrated to stats? If anything it should've been cross-posted to Electronics and DSP!

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23969/designing-butterworth-filter-in-matlab-and-obtaining-filter-a-b-coefficients-a

Answer (score 3):

I migrated it over.  It was an oversight on my part.

[I've cleared the migration history and moved it over to DSP.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/1605/723)

The stats mods have also been informed to clear the migration history and delete the post on their end.

In regards to your statement:

> If anything it should've been cross-posted to Electronics and DSP!

No, it should not.  Cross-posting questions like this on the Stack Exchange network is considered *noise* and is expressly forbidden.